# line breaks in string while binding it with angularjs

Tags: string, angularjs, line, break

i have problem in giving line break in string while binding the data in angularJS

```
<h3  ng-bind="thirdContainHeaderOneTitle"></h3> 
$scope.thirdContainHeaderOneTitle = "my + '<br>' + hdjsd";
```

the `<br>,'<br>',' \/n'` are not working and i dont know why..

Answer (score 3):

See https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngBindHtml along with the [posted example](http://plnkr.co/edit/0vQ21lXuetLxcWrwURpB):

View:

```
<div ng-controller="ngBindHtmlCtrl">
 <p ng-bind-html="myHTML"></p>
</div>
```

Application:

```
angular.module('ngBindHtmlExample', ['ngSanitize'])

.controller('ngBindHtmlCtrl', ['$scope', function ngBindHtmlCtrl($scope) {
  $scope.myHTML =
     'I am an <code>HTML</code>string with <a href="#">links!</a> and other <em>stuff</em>';
}]);
```

Note that you need to include the [ngSanitize module](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ngSanitize).

Answer (score 0):

You can't just bind html in your strings. Try something like this instead.

```
<div ng-bind-html-unsafe="thirdContainHeaderOneTitle"></div>
```

That should parse out your HTMl and give the effect you want.

Answer (score 0):

You cannot sent any html code through the $scope

Its better you use a directive and inside of that , there will be a template, then you can send any html you want like this :

```
  app.directive('yourdirective',function(){
      return {
        restrict:"E",
        template:"my" + "<br>" + "hdjsd"
        } 
   });
```

and in your html :

```
 <yourdirective></yourdirective>
```